# Step by step weather API tutorial

Tags: api

Where can I find a good step by step tutorial about some api weather implementation?

I´m really new in this, so official documentation is not always as clear as I need to begin to understand.

The API must be free, that´s the only requirement.

Note: Originally [posted by me on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196752/step-by-step-weather-api-tutorial) with no answer.

Comment: Are you looking for an API recommendation or a tutorial on using an API?

Comment: @Dave: tutorial on using an API

Answer (score 2):

Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

Note, I recommend using [Yahoo! Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/). Their documentation is nice.